# create table table1 as select .. from sysibm.sysdummy1

Tags: derby, createquery

In DERBY,

I have a table which name is TEST1. I can run this code perfectly.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 AS (SELECT * FROM TEST1) with no data
```

But I can't run this code and derby.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 AS (SELECT ..... FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) with no data
```

editor throws this error :

> ERROR: The CREATE TABLE statement does not include a column list.

ps: "SELECT ..... FROM sysibm.sysdummy1" works with no problem.

How can I create a table with using "select 'columns' from sysibm.sysdummy1" ?

Comment: Please show us your *real* SQL, because obviously, you are **not** using `SELECT ..... FROM sysibm.sysdummy1`

Comment: real sql code is too long to share. it has 4800 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my first code

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 AS (SELECT ..... x, y, z , 0 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) with no data
```

I deleted comma and 0 in query and fixed it! Like that

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 AS (SELECT ..... x, y, z FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) with no data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that the "dummy" table has no columns, and since you specified no columns in your CREATE TABLE statement, Derby is trying to use the columns from the dummy table, and failing to find any, and saying "does not include a column list".

Why not specify the columns you desire in your result table?

For (a little bit) more information about the dummy table, see: http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/SYSIBM-schema-td74269.html

Comment: I don't specify the columns which I desire in my result table because table has more than 200 columns.